# LibGDX writing to text file and receiving various errors

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, libgdx

A game I'm currently creating with LibGDX has a 'High Score' feature in which the high score is saved in a text file and then either written over or read to the screen. I'm getting a multitude of errors here. I tried setting permissions to allow for outside file writing, I tried putting my .txt file in different directories. I tried using `Gdx.files.internal() and Gdx.files.external()` Nothing is working. Here are my two methods for getting and setting the high score.

```
private int getHighScore()
{
    FileHandle scoreFile = Gdx.files.local("data/high_score.txt");
    String text = scoreFile.readString();
    int highScore = Integer.parseInt(text);
    return highScore;
}

private void setHighScore(int newScore)
{
    FileHandle scoreFile = Gdx.files.local("data/high_score.txt");
    String score = Integer.toString(newScore);
    scoreFile.writeString(score, false);
}
```

Upon dying in game (when the score is supposed to be shown), I receive this error from LibGDX:

```
03-06 22:31:37.437: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14533): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 4617
        com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: /data/data/hasherr.floppyfish.android.core/files/data/high_score.txt (Local)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:133)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readString(FileHandle.java:198)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readString(FileHandle.java:186)
        at hasherr.ghostly.main.state.DeathState.getHighScore(DeathState.java:122)
        at hasherr.ghostly.main.state.DeathState.render(DeathState.java:87)
        at hasherr.ghostly.main.state.StateManager.render(StateManager.java:37)
```

Notice here:

> File not found: /data/data/hasherr.floppyfish.android.core/files/data/high_score.txt (Local)

`/data/data/hasherr.floppyfish.android.core/files/data/high_score.txt` is not a directory/file in my game. `data/high_score.txt` is, and that is the file I'm trying to reach. I'm not very familiar with the `Gdx.files.local(path)` method, so I'm not sure where it's grabbing this from.

How do I get my program to use this text file without throwing errors?

Comment: Do you call the `getHighScore` in every rendercycle? If so you should change it and store it instead of getting it from a file the whole time.

Answer (score 3):

First of all i would suggest to make sure, the `Highscores.txt` exists at `Gdx.files.local("data/high_score.txt");`. To do this you can use: `boolean exists = Gdx.files.local("Highscores.txt").exists();`. If this boolean is `false`, instead of reading the `.txt` you could print "no Highscores".
As @MelihYıldız' said the `Gdx.files.local` point to the private app storage. But if you use it to `write` and `read` data you don't need to care about where it is. Just make sure you always use the same `FileHandle`. To know all different Gdx.files.xxx you could read [this](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/FileHandling). It explains, where it stores data and which apptype has access to it.
For `Highscores` you can also think about using `Preferences`. [A quick tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Preferences).
Note, that `Preferences` are the only possibility to store data for HTML5 applications. If you want to make your App a Webapp you should deffinitly think about them.

Answer (score 0):

Gdx uses your applications folder.

From 'File Handling' part of the documentation:

> Files can also be stored on the internal storage, where they are readable and writable. Each installed application has a dedicated internal storage directory. This directory is again only accessible by that application. One can think of this storage as a private working area for the application.

And in the chart you can see the local:

> Local files are stored relative to the application's root or working directory on desktops **and relative to the internal (private)** storage of the application **on Android.** Note that Local and internal are mostly the same on the desktop.

You should use `Gdx.files.internal("data/high_score.txt");` instead, if you want to store in devices internal storage.

The reference link: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling

Comment: Gdx.files.internal is READ ONLY! For this highscores i would suggest to use the libgdx `Preferences`. Easy to use and work also for web apps (only way to store persistent data in libgdx web app).